# objectoutputstream writeobject gets stuck

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I am working on a remote control program in Java and I am using sockets for the connection, and `ObjectOutputStream`, `ObjectInputStream` to transfer data between the computers.

My program is built from server side that processes and forwards the data it receives, and clients side which are the user that connects.

I am transferring a screenshot of the remote computer using `Robot` class. This is how I send the screenshots:

```
public void send_screenshots() throws java.io.IOException{
  stop = false; // if the connections should stop
  screenshot_sender = new java.util.Timer();
  // screens is the connected graphicsdevices array.
  final java.awt.Robot r=new java.awt.Robot(screens[current_screen]);
  screenshot_sender.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        if (!stop) {
           try {
        outputstream.reset(); // had to write it, made too many problems (in other part of the code) when I didn't reset…
          // I convert the BufferedImage to byte[] so I will be able to write it
              outputstream.writeObject(ImagetoByteArray(r.createScreenCapture(screens[current_screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds()));
           outputstream.flush();
              System.out.println("sent");
           } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        } else {
           System.out.println("STOPPED SENDING SCREENSHOTS");
           cancel();
           screenshot_sender.cancel();
        }
     }
  }, 1500, 100);
}
```

This works, until I am trying to switch to another screen, it sends for 3 times and stops sending. I tried saving the screenshot as a file (to see if it is correct) and it is okay. I added `System.out.println("line");` after every line of the above code and the code get stuck on the writeObject call.

Why does it get stuck?

The outputstream is set when the client connects, like this:

```
outputstream = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: You are sending faster than the peer is receiving.

Comment: so I should slow down the sending timer¿
It would make the controling inconvenient because the controling side would recieve the screenshots with too big delay

Comment: From some reason the timer stops, I don't know why…
I even tried to catch Exception (and not IOException) but it didn't help

Comment: It isn't 'convenient' how it is either. See if you can speed up the receiving side,

Comment: It works when I speed up the receiving side, but it starts an old problem, but I will think of something… thank you☺